# Check if a number from 1 to N has a number 3 in it

Tags: algorithm

How do I check how many numbers from 1 to N (N < 100) have number 3 in it without converting it to a string to check it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977456/how-to-check-if-a-int-var-contains-a-specific-number

Answer (score 3):

You can use th `%` mod operator to take the digits of the number one by one, and check them with `3`.

Like,

```
int x;
while(num != 0)        // num here goes from 1 to 100
{
    x = num % 10;
    if(x == 3)
    {
        //eureka
    }
    num /= 10;
}
```

**EDIT**

Lets check the algorithm for `35`.

*First iteration*

```
//num = 35

x = num % 10;           // x = 5 (35 % 10)
if(x == 3)             // is x equal to 3 (NO)
{
    //eureka
}
num /= 10;             // num = 3 (35 / 10)
```

While loop check

```
num != 0              // num = 5
```

*Second Iteration*

//num = 35

```
x = num % 10;           // x = 3 (5 % 10)
if(x == 3)             // is x equal to 3 (YES)
{
    //eureka
}
num /= 10;             // num = 0 (5 / 10)
```

While loop check

```
num != 0              // num = 0
                      // While loop exits
```

Comment: And when you get to 30? 30 % 10 = 0, 31 % 10 = 1, 32 % 10 = 2

Comment: Its not `30 % 3`. Its `30 % 10`.

Comment: can you update the question with the new code. Make an **EDIT** section update

Comment: The code that you wrote, that you said is not working.

Comment: I didn't use your code because I don't even know that programming language (java maybe?) and because your algorithm is incorrect (or maybe I didn't understand your code because of the reason mentioned above).What your code does is that it checks the remainder of a number (from 1 to N ; N<100) divided by 10, right?If that's the case then it won't work because when you check for remainder of numbers from 30-39 you won't get 3 as a remainder (only 33 %10 = 3).

Comment: @user3711671 The algorithm is correct. If you can only understand code in some specific language, please indicate that in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is by remainder and checking if number is between 30 and 39

```
if((x%10)==3||(x<40&&x>=30))
{
//Thats it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the modulas operator `%` such that if(n % 3 == 1){success operation}